# Python - Call Variable within Variable in a Function

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm reading a JSON file and extracting certain data from that file. One of my variables extracts a global envName variable and sets that = to fi_var. I would like the next variable in my function to use fi_var as a variable since fi_var is set to the correct FI. This way I don't have to pass in the FI for each variable. There are other areas where I could benefit from this capability also. If I can get it to work once I can repeat the behavior. I'm new to Python so please excuse me if I don't use the correct terminology.

EXAMPLE.

```
with open ('F5EnvRules.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)`

def prodwebapp ():
    fi_var = data["GLOBAL"]["Prod - envName"] # fi_var = the FI after reading the JSON file
    fi_www_node_port_var = data["FI"]["portNumber"] # Want to replace "FI" with fi_var
    fi_www_node_name = data["FI"]["nodeIP_1"] # Same here
    fi_web_snat_var = data["FI"]["snatIP"] # Same here
prodwebapp()
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Why not just literally replace `"FI"` with `fi_var`

Comment: I agree with @gommb . For example, use `fi_www_node_port_var = data[fi_var]["portNumber"]`

Comment: I tried replacing "FI" with ""fi_var"" and I received an invalid syntax error. I need the variable to have quotes around it, that's why I used "" "". Here's what my script looks like. 

def prodwebapp ():
 fi_var = data["GLOBAL"]["Prod - envName"]
 fi_www_node_port_var = data[""fi_var""]["portNumber"]

Comment: You don't need to put quotes around string variables.